# In Hazelcast jet how to Sink Map object to BatchSource?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am new to Hazelcast jet and I am not getting how to Sink simple java.util.Map to BatchSource?

I have tried below but not seems to be working.

```
Map<String, Object> data =new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("xyz", "abc");
```

Way 1:

```
Map<String, Object> am = jetInstance.getMap("abc");
        am.putAll(data);
        
         BatchSource batchSource = Sources.map("abc");
```

I gives error: `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry`

Way 2: `BatchSource batchSource = TestSources.items(data);`

and same error please help what wrong am I doing I am trying to creating pipeline but not going forward.

Comment: Please provide a full example of what doesn't work for you. The first way should work fine, see this working example: https://gist.github.com/frant-hartm/5fedcf66ea61e3e8db119b9f06742844

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem must be somewhere other than in the code you've shared; the BatchSource definition isn't incorrect.  I just did a quick test and the following runs fine (Tested on 5.0 version):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.getJetConfig().setEnabled(true);
    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    Map<String,Object> map = hz.getMap("map");
    map.put("A", "AnObject");
    map.put("B", "AnotherObject");
    BatchSource source = Sources.map("map");
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
    p.readFrom(source)
            .writeTo(Sinks.logger());
    hz.getJet().newJob(p).join();

}
```

With output:

```
INFO: [192.168.86.25]:5701 [dev] [5.0] Start execution of job '0702-23dd-8800-0001', execution 0702-23dd-8801-0001 from coordinator [192.168.86.25]:5701
Oct 25, 2021 9:11:44 AM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.connector.WriteLoggerP
INFO: [192.168.86.25]:5701 [dev] [5.0] [0702-23dd-8800-0001/loggerSink#0] B=AnotherObject
Oct 25, 2021 9:11:44 AM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.connector.WriteLoggerP
INFO: [192.168.86.25]:5701 [dev] [5.0] [0702-23dd-8800-0001/loggerSink#0] A=AnObject
Oct 25, 2021 9:11:44 AM com.hazelcast.jet.impl.MasterJobContext
INFO: [192.168.86.25]:5701 [dev] [5.0] Execution of job '0702-23dd-8800-0001', execution 0702-23dd-8801-0001 completed successfully
```

(Since a map is unordered in this case the entries are seen in a different order than the way they were added to the map)